# How can I add a listener to each ListCell created in my ListView to 1. get the data in that cell and 2. call a method?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm creating a mockup of a Java version of the in-house database for my company. I successfully display all entries (in this case customers) in the list view, but I want to be able to call a method and get the data from the cell. For example, if I clicked a customer with a customer ID of 498, I'd want to have some way to access the ID(498) and then display more info for that customer ID. I can handle displaying all the info myself, I'm just struggling with how to access the data inside the cells. Relevant code:

Controller Class Snippet that populates the list view:

```
package com.verus.techtracker_2;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class MainViewController {
ObservableList<ObservableList> data = 
FXCollections.observableArrayList();
@FXML
private Label welcomeText;
@FXML
private ListView<ObservableList> OrgTbl2;
private orgmodel org;
@FXML
private static Connection conn;
private static final String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://10.9.32.46:1433;database=TechTracker;integratedSecurity=true";

public MainViewController() {
}

public static Connection connect() throws SQLException {
    try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
        System.err.println("Error: "+cnfe.getMessage());
    }catch(InstantiationException ie){
        System.err.println("Error: "+ie.getMessage());
    }catch(IllegalAccessException iae){
        System.err.println("Error: "+iae.getMessage());
    }

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    return conn;
}

public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    if(conn !=null && !conn.isClosed())
        return conn;
    connect();
    return conn;


}

public void initialize (URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    loadData();
}
ResultSet rs = null;
public void loadData() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    getConnection();


    ObservableList<orgmodel> OrganizationObservableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    try{
        PreparedStatement ps = connect().prepareStatement("SELECT CustomerName,CustomerID, Inactive FROM dbo.tbCustomers");
        rs=ps.executeQuery();
        System.out.println(rs);


        /**
         * ******************************
         * Data added to ObservableList *
         *******************************
         */
        while (rs.next()) {
            //Iterate Row
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                //Iterate Column
                row.add(rs.getString(i));
            }
            System.out.println("Row [1] added " + row);
            data.add(row);
            org = new orgmodel(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getBoolean(3));
            OrganizationObservableList.add(org);


        }

        //FINALLY ADDED TO TableView
        OrgTbl2.setItems(data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error on Building Data");
    }
}


}
```

FXML file of this scene:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="1000.0" prefWidth="1920.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.verus.techtracker_2.MainViewController">
   <children>
      <VBox layoutX="130.0" layoutY="58.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ListView fx:id="OrgTbl2" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="6.0" onMouseClicked="#loadData" prefHeight="987.0" prefWidth="958.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't make much sense. Since you have an `Orgmodel` class, why aren't you using that to populate the `ListView`, instead of populating it using a list to represent each row? Then you can just register a listener with the selection in the usual way: `orgTbl2.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(...)` and do whatever you need with the selected item.

Comment: The data isn’t in the cells, it is in the model which backs the list view (observable list of all items, selected items in the selection model, etc).  The cells are just a visual representation of the portion of the data visible at a given time.  Given a cell you can call [`getItem`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#getItem()) to determine the item currently associated with that cell *at that point in time*, but, generally, you are better off working with listeners on the model classes, as in James’ answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think when you say

> For example, if I clicked a customer with a customer ID of 498,

you're referring to responding if the user selects an item in the `ListView`. All you need to do is register a listener with the selection, using

```
orgTbl2.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(...)
```

This will be much easier if you make your `ListView` display model instances, instead of using a `List` to represent each row. You already appear to have a model class called `OrgModel` defined.

Here is a version of your code which does this. I have removed all the unnecessary code, reverted to standard naming conventions, and made some other "clean-ups" so that other users can read the code easily.

```
package com.verus.techtracker_2;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class MainViewController {

    @FXML
    private Label welcomeText;
    @FXML
    private ListView<OrgModel> orgTbl2;

    private static Connection conn ;
    private static final String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://10.9.32.46:1433;database=TechTracker;integratedSecurity=true";
    
    public void initialize (URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        loadData();

        orgTbl2.getSelectionModel()
            .selectedItemProperty()
            .addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {

            if (newSelection != null) {
                // assuming names of property accessor methods:
                String customerName = newSelection.getCustomerName();
                String id = newSelection.getId();
                boolean inactive = newSelection.isInactive();
                // do whatever you need with the data:
                System.out.println("Selected customer id: " + id);
        });

        // display customer name in listview:
        orgTbl2.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(OrgModel item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty || item == null) {
                    setText("");
                } else {
                    setText(item.getCustomerName());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadData() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    
        ObservableList<OrgModel> organizationObservableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    
        try{
            PreparedStatement ps = connect().prepareStatement("SELECT CustomerName,CustomerID, Inactive FROM dbo.tbCustomers");
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            System.out.println(rs);

            while (rs.next()) {
                OrgModel org = new OrgModel(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getBoolean(3));
                organizationObservableList.add(organizationObservableList);
            }
            orgTbl2.setItems(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error on Building Data");
        }
    }

    private static Connection connect() throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
            System.err.println("Error: "+cnfe.getMessage());
        }catch(InstantiationException ie){
            System.err.println("Error: "+ie.getMessage());
        }catch(IllegalAccessException iae){
            System.err.println("Error: "+iae.getMessage());
        }
    
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        return conn;
    }
    
    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        if(conn !=null && !conn.isClosed())
            return conn;
        conn = connect();
        return conn;
    }    

}
```

If you really want to specifically respond to mouse clicks, instead of selection changes, you can do so in the cell. Note this means, for example, if the user changes selection using the keyboard then there will be no response to this change. This might be useful though if you wanted only to respond to double-clicks on a cell, etc.

```
public void initialize (URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    loadData();

    // display customer name in listview:
    orgTbl2.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<>() {

        {
            setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                OrgModel item = getItem();
                if (item != null) {
                    String id = item.getId();
                    String customerName = item.getCustomerName();
                    boolean inactive = item.isInactive();
                    // etc ...
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(OrgModel item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty || item == null) {
                setText("");
            } else {
                setText(item.getCustomerName());
            }
        }
    });
}
```